# SPLUNK data trim

Tags: splunk

we are facing an issue where there is enough space in our index but our disk space has reached around 80%. SO just want to know if volume trimming happens on the disk level as well? Below attached are our index configuration for paloalto index and the disk status.

```
[firewall_paloalto]
coldPath = volume:cold\firewall_paloalto\colddb 
homePath = volume:hotwarm\firewall_paloalto\db
thawedPath=D:\splunk_data\firewall_paloalto\thaweddb 
tstatsHomePath = volume:hotwarm\firewall_paloalto\datamodel_summary 
frozenTimePeriodinSecs=47304000
maxTotalDataSizeMB=4294967295
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have "enough space in [y]our index" if there is enough disk space

Splunk rolls data on the following conditions:

- maximum index size reached
- maximum retention reached
- out of disk space

If you run out of disk space, Splunk starts rolling data out of Hot/Warm into Cold (or, out of Cold into Frozen) as it sees fit - it's not entirely predictable as to what will be rolled first

To mitigate against disk space being your rolling condition you can either:

- shrink the maximum sizes of all indices using that storage point
- add disk space

Comment: I want to ask we have enough space in our index and our disk is 80% used , but still data is being trimmed , so I want to ask if volume trimming happens on disk level ?

Comment: @SiddharthNegi - I answered that herein :)